# URLClassLoader addURL() Java 16 Illegal reflective access

Tags: java, reflection, urlclassloader, java-16

i currently developing a "addon" based system for my minecraft server. Now i have a problem. if i run it on Java 16, it throws a "Illegal Reflection Exception" and the operation will be denied. I try to call the addURL() method from URLClassLoader.

Here is my code:

```
try {
  addURL = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
  addURL.setAccessible(true);
} catch (final Throwable e) {
    e.printStackStrace();
}
```

Can someone help me to solve that? How i can make that possible in java 16?

Thanks for help

Comment: If you are create the URLClassLoader then you can override the addURL method to do what you want.

Comment: Yea but that does not allow me to add my classes to a other classloader, which is not mine

Comment: Correct but you can delegate by specifying the URLClassLoader as the parent.